# Add array to List with specific key

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I try to add a string[] to a List

Code:

```
foreach (int software_id in softwarelist)
{
    String sqlstring = "SELECT SoftwareName, Task_idn_Install, Task_idn_Deinstall, KZ, ParameterFeld FROM TUI_Software WHERE Sw_idn = '" + software_id + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, con);
    SqlDataReader result_sw_info = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    if (result_sw_info.HasRows)
    {
        result_sw_info.Read();

        softwarename = result_sw_info[0].ToString();
        task_idn_install = result_sw_info[1].ToString();
        task_idn_deinstall = result_sw_info[2].ToString();
        indicator = result_sw_info[3].ToString();
        parameter = result_sw_info[4].ToString();

        string[] software_data = new string[] {sw_id, softwarename, task_idn_install, task_idn_deinstall, indicator, parameter };

        softwarelist_insert.Add(software_data);
    }
    result_sw_info.Close();
}
```

So the keys in the softwarelist_insert begins with 0. But how can I add the software_data with the key software_id  in the foreach. Cause I want to identifier the arrys in the list with the software_id.

Comment: Watch out for your [SQL injection vulnerability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: yeah this was just an example I found. Used in orginial code pdo.

Comment: do you need to have it in an array or can you create an object to hold the software information and have a list of that

Comment: I can also create objects.

Comment: If you want to specify arbitrary ids then you should not be using a List in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a System.Collections.Generic [`Dictionary<string, string[]>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a `List<string[]>`.

```
var softwarelist_insert = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
...
softwarelist_insert.Add(software_id, software_data);
```

Better still, use a strongly typed object instead of a string[].

```
public class SoftwareData {
  public string SoftwareName { get; set; }
  public string TaskIdnInstall { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

and then

```
var softwarelist_insert = new Dictionary<string, SoftwareData>();
...
var = new SoftwareData {
  SoftwareName = result_sw_info[0].ToString(),
  TaskIdnInstall = result_sw_info[1].ToString(),
}
softwarelist_insert.Add(software_id, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own type and add the data to it.
First create a class like this

```
public class softwarelist_insert_class
{
  public string ID {get;set;}
  public List<string>softwarelist_insert{get;set;}
}
```

Then you can create a list variable of this type

```
List<softwarelist_insert_class> variable_name=new List<softwarelist_insert_class>();
```

Then you can add data to it like:

```
List<string> software_data = List<string> {sw_id, softwarename, task_idn_install, task_idn_deinstall, indicator, parameter };

variable_name.Add({id,software_data});
```